# Deleting a Review Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I believe I'm having a routing problem: I have a feature that allows users to leave a review of a specific individual.  So I have a reviews model and a individuals model.  I'm trying to find a way to delete specific reviews on that individual.

Routes.rb:

```
    resources :individuals do
      collection do
        get 'search'
      end
      collection do
        get 'schools'
      end
      member do
        post 'flag', :individuals
      end
      resources :reviews  do
        member do
          post 'flag', 'vote', 'downvote',  :review
        end
        resources :reviews, only: [:index, :create]


      end

  end

  resources :reviews, only: [:destroy, :update, :edit]
```

So I believe if I've done this right I'll have nested for the reviews index and create: `individuals/1/reviews/2` but not for actions destroy, update and edit: `reviews/1/edit`.

Reviews Controller:

```
 def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @professor, notice: 'Review was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

View.html.rb:

```
  <% if @review.blank? %>
  Nothing to review!
  <% else %>
  <div class="list-group">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <% @review.each do |review| %>
        <li class="list-group-item">  <%= review.comment %> Review Flagged:
          <%= pluralize(review.flag, 'time') %>.   <%= link_to 'View', professor_review_path(review.professor, review) %>
           <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_individual_review_path(review.individual, review) %>
           <%= link_to 'Delete', destroy_review_path(review), data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this review?"} %> </li>
        <% end %>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

The view page does not work I get a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy_review_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb095e46e28>:0x007fb09d1afdb0>
Did you mean?  edit_review_path
```

I have gotten this to work for deleting individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No routing issue here :)

This is just a hard-to-understand-at-first subtlety of RESTful routing.

If you run `rake routes` you will see the definitions for all your routes.

```
GET    /reviews          reviews#index    reviews_path
POST   /reviews          reviews#create   
GET    /reviews/new      reviews#new      new_review_path
GET    /reviews/:id/edit reviews#edit     edit_review_path
GET    /reviews/:id      reviews#show     review_path
PUT    /reviews/:id      reviews#update   
DELETE /reviews/:id      reviews#destroy
```

You will notice that there is no `as:` naming for some of the routes.

This is because the route names match the URL path, not the controller or action.

Notice that the routes that use the same URL path also use the same route name.

And a single RESTful route may use 4 different verb types (i.e. `GET`, `POST`, `PUT/PATCH`, `DELETE`) for a single route.

The correct link code is as follows:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', review_path(review), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this review?"} %> </li>
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much.   You really helped me through this, one other problem I was having which I solved is that I had a before_action that set the individual but I changed it: `  before_action :set_professor, :except => [:flag, :vote, :destroy]` and it works now.

Comment: Hey no problem, mind checkmarking this as the answer? Also, using `before_action, expect: [:action]` I find kind of dangerous... Not sure what you're context is, but I 100% always do `before_action, only: [:action]` instead.